# BIRT report chart with multiple bar graphs

Tags: sql, birt

So I've created a data set to give me the count of trip tickets done in the year grouped by the month. This gives me 13 columns because the first is for the type of the ticket and the other 12 columns are the counts for the months of the year. But now when creating a chart in BIRT designer I need to show 12 bar graphs in one chart area where each one shows the count of tickets for each type for the month.
Below is how my data looks like in the query results:

```
Type | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec
============================================================================
LOW VOLT.   33  45  109 69  3   1   0   1   39  67  57  52
PNEUMATIC   0   0   1   0   0   64  62  11  0   1   0   0
ELECT   182 149 205 242 200 245 201 199 217 264 217 167
MECH    26  58  53  52  17  53  32  45  45  67  59  31
B A S   0   1   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0
FAX 87  81  107 114 96  145 107 84  83  105 101 90
HVAC    1   1   100 135 75  2   0   1   1   9   0   0
CIVIL   113 87  142 154 114 163 104 101 137 131 153 117
PHOTOCOPY   170 124 206 175 130 222 119 128 147 185 188 157
A/c 224 212 348 421 260 504 403 379 446 442 391 292
```

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I just changed my SELECT query to take a count of 1 for each record then summed up the counts in my graph.